# One user can access network share folder while the other user should not on the same window 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, permissions, wired-networking

I have a Windows 7 machine with shared folders on it. I have 2 users, an administrator and a regular user account.
I want the shared folders on this machine to be available to the administrator account only.

Comment: What have you tried? What Operating systems. Have you tried setting permissions. We'll need some more details to help you

Comment: Hi Joe, I am using windows 7 machine. I have two accounts on the machine one is administrator and the other one is standard account. I want that the administrator account can access shared folder which are shared over the network whereas the standard user should not be able to even browse the network shares.

Answer (score 0):

Rahul, You need to set permissions on these folders to disallow the other user.
If you go into the sharing permissions on these folders you can modify the permissions to only allow access the users you want to give access to. As you only have 1 other user you can use the deny permission on that user account and they will not be able to open the folders.
To stop the users browsing the folders on the local machine you will need to set file/folder level permissions. Again open up properties, go into security and modify the rights so the user does not have access. Again specific deny permissions on this user account will suffice in this case.